# How to combine two .xls files by the first part of a file's name in a large directory using R?

Tags: r

I have a directory of 100 **.xls** files, two for each state (one for Schools, one for Universities). They all have a similar naming convention like this:

```
Alabama - Schools - 2018-03-28
Alabama - Universities - 2018-03-28
Alaska - Schools - 2018-03-28
Alaska - Universities - 2018-03-28
```

I would like to first combine the files by state name into an .xlsx file, and then rename the tabs within the .xlsx file to "schools" and "universities".

The output would be 50 .xlsx files (one for each state) with two tabs: "schools" and "universities". Each of these 50 files would be simply named after its state. ("Alabama.xlsx" and "Alaska.xlsx", for example.)

Any advice for how to achieve this? It's unclear to me how to merge two files by the first portion of a file's name. (In the example above, merging by "Alabama" only and not the rest of the file name.)

I appreciate any help.

Comment: but each of the 100 xls files can be completely stored in just one table?

Comment: Ultimately I need the output to be 50 .xlsx files, one file for each state.

Comment: I am working on the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try and give me a feedback. If it works I will explain step by step.

```
country <- c("Alabama", "Alaska")
ref <- c("School", "Universities")


apply(expand.grid(country, ref), 1, paste, collapse=" - ")


file_names <- paste0(apply(expand.grid(country, ref), 1, paste, collapse=" - ")," - 2018-03-28.xls")


read_df <- data.frame(path = paste0(getwd(), file_names), file_names = file_names,
                      country = unlist(lapply(strsplit(file_names, "-"), `[[`, 1)),
                      ref = unlist(lapply(strsplit(file_names, "-"), `[[`, 2)),
                      final_name = paste0(unlist(lapply(strsplit(file_names, "-"), `[[`, 1)), ".xlsx"))

require(xlsx)

for (i in country) {
        assign(read_df[read_df$country ==  i & read_df$ref == "School", "file_names"],
               read.xlsx(read_df[read_df$country ==  i & read_df$ref == "School", "path"]),
               envir = .GlobalEnv)
        assign(read_df[read_df$country ==  i & read_df$ref == "Universities", "file_names"],
               read.xlsx(read_df[read_df$country ==  i & read_df$ref == "Universities", "path"]),
               envir = .GlobalEnv)
        write.xlsx(get(read_df[read_df$country ==  i & read_df$ref == "School", "file_names"]),
                   file = d_df[read_df$country ==  i & read_df$ref == "School", "final_name"],
                   sheetName="schools", row.names=FALSE)
        write.xlsx(get(read_df[read_df$country ==  i & read_df$ref == "Universities", "file_names"]),
                   file=d_df[read_df$country ==  i & read_df$ref == "School", "final_name"],
                   sheetName="universities",
                   append=TRUE, row.names=FALSE)
}
```

Comment: I think this gives me what I need. Thanks so much!